# NextJs: The Serverless Function exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment, next.js, vercel

I'm new working with NextJs and when trying to deploy my project to Vercel I'm getting the following error:

> Error! The Serverless Function "api/auth" is 50.55mb which exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb.

I have spent a lot of my time trying to find a proper answer but I didn't find any. Here is the code of the api request I'm making:

```
const { auth: adminAuth } = require("firebase/admin");

export default async function auth(req, res) {
  const tokenId = req.query.token;
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    adminAuth
      .verifyIdToken(tokenId)
      .then((user) => {
        res.json(user);
        resolve();
      })
      .catch(() => {
        res.status(302).send("Invalid authentication");
        resolve();
      });
  });
}
```

I'll be really grateful if anybody can help me, thanks y'all!

Comment: Also, when deleting the file the error disappears, so I don't know if I have to make some config before deploying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next.js 12.3 includes the dependencies you specified in `package.json` as well as their dependencies in the build thus potentially increasing the build size until the current maximum of 50MB is reached.

In my case it was the `pdfjs-dist` package that had `canvas` as a dependency. It is enough to list `pdfjs-dist` as a dependency in `package.json` to make Vercel builds fails. It does not even matter if you actually import any file from the packages.

```
Error: The Serverless Function "api/***" is 64.75mb which exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb.
```

**Finding the culprit**

The Vercel build logs should list the packages included in the build along with their size. In our case:

```
All dependencies                                        208.68 MB         57.14 MB
Serverless Function's page: api/***
Large Dependencies                              Uncompressed size  Compressed size
node_modules/canvas/build                               164.01 MB         42.82 MB
node_modules/sharp/vendor                                16.13 MB          6.76 MB
...
```

**Excluding packages from a build**

The `canvas` dependency was not required in our case. To exclude a package from the bundle and thus reduce the size for the serverless functions:

- With Next.js 13.3 the [`experimental.outputFileTracingExcludes`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output#caveats) key in your `next.config.js` should allow excluding a package

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    outputFileTracingRoot: path.join(__dirname, '../../'),
    outputFileTracingExcludes: {
      '*': [
        'node_modules/canvas',
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

- Since I was using Next.js 12.3 and Yarn I ended up replacing the dependency with a stub by using [the following](https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/103#discussioncomment-5500414) in `package.json`:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "canvas": "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@favware/skip-dependency/-/skip-dependency-1.2.1.tgz"
  }
```

Similar workarounds should exist for NPM.

Answer (score 4):

I've been dealing with the same issue. It appears that when bundling the serverless function vercel is pulling in ALL assets within your project. So 50.55MB is likely the size of your current entire build. I'm researching how to only include certain files within the vercel.json but have so far not figured exactly how to do that. For now you could probably just remove a few files from your public assets to get under the limit.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I never figured out what the issue was, but for my scenario, removing the `.next` and `.vercel` folders and built the project again fixed the issue. I think in some cases like in mine, that folder can cache some of the assets or previous pages information. But as you mentioned, I think a great idea would be to include specific files within the `vercel.json` file to be more in control of the deploy build.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely caused by `firebase/admin` including everything in the `firebase` package, not just the "admin" parts.

You can verify this by creating a file with only the import and running `@vercel/nft` to trace the files.

```
npm init -y
npm add firebase
echo "const { auth: adminAuth } = require('firebase/admin')" > index.js
npm i -g @vercel/nft
nft print index.js
```

The entire [`firebase`](https://packagephobia.com/result?p=firebase@9.9.2) package is quite large, so its best to follow the recommendation from the firebase team and use the [`firebase-admin`](https://packagephobia.com/result?p=firebase-admin@11.0.1) package inside Serverless Functions.

> This SDK (`firebase`) is intended for end-user client access from environments such as the Web, mobile Web (e.g. React Native, Ionic), Node.js desktop (e.g. Electron), or IoT devices running Node.js. If you are instead interested in using a Node.js SDK which grants you admin access from a privileged environment (like a server), you should use the Firebase Admin Node.js SDK (`firebase-admin`).
>
> *source: [firebase NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase/v/9.7.1-20220505222723)*

Answer (score 2):

add this to your next.config

```js
 experimental: {
    outputFileTracingIgnores: ["**canvas**"],
  },
```

Comment: your answer works but gives a warning:

warn  - `outputFileTracingIgnores` has been moved to `experimental.outputFileTracingExcludes`. Please update your next.config.js file accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone getting this error I found that it was caused by nextjs including swc and esbuild dependencies in my serverless functions when it didn't need to. The fix was to add this to my `next.config.js`

```js
 experimental: {
    outputFileTracingExcludes: {
      '*': [
        'node_modules/@swc/core-linux-x64-gnu',
        'node_modules/@swc/core-linux-x64-musl',
        'node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64',
      ],
    },
  },
```

Comment: are you using pnpm? I'm migrating from yarn to pnpm rn & all of a sudden this has become an issue for me. It's only an issue w pnpm builds.

Comment: This happened right after migrating from npm to pnpm

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the `canvas` dependency of `pdfjs-dist` and adding an override to my `package.json` (pnpm) solved the issue.

```
"pnpm": {
  "overrides": {
    "canvas": "../_EXCLUDED_"
  }
},
```

Answer (score -2):

You could add `.vercelignore` file to avoid this

Ref: https://vercel.com/guides/prevent-uploading-sourcepaths-with-vercelignore

```
# Ignore everything (folders and files) on root only
/*
!api
!vercel.json
!*.html
!*.css
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This wont work because `.vercelignore` only ignores input files but the issue is the output size (the traced files that end up in the output).